# Xamarin BLE implementation of OnCharacteristicValueChanged has poor performance

Tags: android, xamarin, mono, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been implementing an application which streams data from a BLE device. For some background, this device sends out data over the connection interval of 11.25ms. I am currently developing on a Nexus 9 Tablet running Marshmallow.

Connecting to the devices, and R/W of characteristics seems to work well. The problem occurs once I begin subscribing to the characteristic Notification, triggering the BluetoothGattCallback.OnCharacteristicChanged() callback. My app immediately jumps up from 4% to 15% CPU.

Taking the current byte value from the callback using the characteristic.GetValue() method takes even longer, bumping CPU up to ~30%. Looking at DDMS, it looks like OnCharacteristicChanged() starts taking tons of CPU time. Additionally, GC starts running constantly,

I have implemented this in Android studio, with a total CPU usage of <5%, with the OnCharaceristicChanged() callback taking up far less CPU time. It seems to me that either there is some issue with the threadpool allocations for the CharacteristicChanged callback, or some other issue in the mono Android.Bluetooth implementation.

[Native App Trace For Characteristic Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZybq.png)
[Xamarin App Trace For Characteristic Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfoKl.png)

```
06-17 10:53:08.577 D/Mono    ( 6303): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 1   num_hash_entries 1 sccs size 1 init 0.00ms df1 0.01ms sort 0.04ms dfs2 0.00ms setup-cb 0.00ms free-data 0.00ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
06-17 10:53:08.578 D/Mono    ( 6303): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 3.49ms, total 3.75ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 0K major 3248K los 251K
06-17 10:53:09.771 D/Mono    ( 6303): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 1 num_hash_entries 1 sccs size 1 init 0.00ms df1 0.01ms sort 0.04ms dfs2 0.00ms setup-cb 0.00ms free-data 0.00ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
06-17 10:53:09.771 D/Mono    ( 6303): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 4.45ms, total 5.95ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 0K major 3248K los 251K
06-17 10:53:10.954 D/Mono    ( 6303): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 1 num_hash_entries 1 sccs size 1 init 0.00ms df1 0.01ms sort 0.04ms dfs2 0.00ms setup-cb 0.00ms free-data 0.00ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
```